# excel - generate a username from a full name field

Tags: macos, mac, microsoft-excel, sql

I'm trying to generate a username using a single name field in excel which has the person's first name and last name. I'm open to what the username would be, as long as its intuitive for the user. The name fields can be tricky, as the data looks like this:

```
Albert Abongo (2 names)
Stephen Michael Essuah Ackah (4 names)
Alhaji Iddrisu Abdul-KArim (3 names)
```

I guess my ideal usernames for these people would be

```
aabongo
sackah
aabdul-karim
```

Comment: is the `(2 names)` part of the string?

Comment: Do you (or might you) have any users with the same name? If so, any solution needs to have a built-in strategy for avoiding duplicate usernames.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the following (with the input data in A1):

`=LOWER(LEFT(A1,1)&TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),LEN(A1))))`

- `LOWER`: makes all output lowercase
- `LEFT(A1,1)`: pulls the data, starting from the left, for 1 character long.
- `&` links the two parts together
- `TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),(LEN(A1)))`

  - the `SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",LEN(A1)))` function counts the length of the original string and places the same number of spaces where every space exists
  - then the `(RIGHT(text,LEN(A1))` pulls, starting from the right, for the length of the original string
  - `TRIM` removes the leading spaces

Comment: It would be a better answer and more in line with the Stack ethos if you explained WHY.

Comment: @JulianKnight better?

Comment: If any of the names have trailing spaces, you will need to replace each instance of `A1` in the formula with `TRIM(A1)`.

Comment: @CameronAziz: Nice one.

Comment: It may be because I am trying open office and google spreadsheet, but this formula gives me data like this: aabongo, smichael essuah ackua (last names still present), aiddrisu abdul-kharim (same problem)

Comment: Yes, it is because you are on google spreadsheet. Spreadsheet (and I assume open office) has a size limit to the width of the cell (I believe its 256 char), so it fails when it adds all the 255 spaces times the number of original spaces.

Use this formula for google spreadsheets, untested on open office.
`=LOWER(LEFT(A1,1)&TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",50)),50)))`

Comment: I suggest using `LEN(A1)` instead of `255` in all instances.

Comment: @Excellll nice!!

Comment: this new code should work in google spreadsheets as well as open office.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to the clever answer from @CameronAziz, if you want to avoid duplicate usernames, you can add another column to the right of those usernames (in column B in this example), and fill down this formula:

```
=B1&IF(COUNTIF($B$1:B1,B1)>1,COUNTIF($B$1:B1,B1),"")
```

This will append a number to the right of the username if it is a duplicate of any previous usernames.

[image]